# The setwise stabiliser of a finite set is maximal in Sym(N). 

Tags: permutations

So I'm reading a paper which assumes the following statement but I would like to be able to prove it.

Let $S=Sym\(\mathbb{N}\)$ denote the symmetric group on the set of natural numbers.

If $ \emptyset\subset A \subset \mathbb{N}$ then: 
 $$S_{A}= \{ q \in S : aq\in A,\;\forall a\in A \} $$  is a maximal subgroup of $ S.$

Here is how I would like to prove it. I select $f\in S\setminus S_{\{A\}}.$ I want to show that $\langle S_{\{A\}}, f \rangle = S$, otherwise we have a contradiction. So i take $g\in S$. If $g\in S_{\{A\}}$ or $g=f$ we are done so assume   $ g\in S\setminus (S_{\{A\}}\cup f ).$ How can I show that $g\in \langle S_{\{A\}}, f \rangle$? I had thought about doing something like finding $h\in\langle S_{\{A\}}, f \rangle$ such that  $gh\in S_{\{A\}}$ so that $g=ghh^{-1}\in\langle S_{\{A\}}, f \rangle$ but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28302/the-setwise-stabiliser-of-a-finite-set-is-maximal-in-symn

Comment: If you're going to cross-post a question to multiple web sites, please say so.  That way, people can avoid duplication of effort.

Answer (score 2):

If both $A$ and its complement are infinite,  you probably want $S_A$ to consist of permutations $q$ such that both $q$ and $q^{-1}$ map $A$ into itself; otherwise, your $S_A$ isn't a group.  But then let $G$ the set of permutations $q\in S$ such that $q(A)$ differs from $A$ by only a finite set (i.e., both $q(A)-A$ and $A-q(A)$ are finite).  This $G$ seems to be a subgroup strictly between (the corrected version of) $S_A$ and $S$.

For finite $A$ (or finite $\mathbb N-A$), on the other hand, the result seems to be correct.  I'll post a proof later if I have time, if my proof holds up, and if nobody else posts a proof first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of how the proof should go when $A$ is finite.  To avoid excessive notation, I'll assume $|A|=3$, but I trust it will be clear that the method is general.  Suppose $G$ were a subgroup strictly between $S_A$ and $S$.  Contemplate the coset spaces (with $S$-action) $S/S_A$ and $S/G$.  The former is isomorphic to the family $P_3$ of all 3-element subsets of $\mathbb N$ with the obvious $S$-action.  $S/G$ has to be a non-trivial quotient of this, by an $S$-equivariant equivalence relation $E$; here "non-trivial" means that $E$ is neither the equality relation nor the relation that makes all elements of $P_3$ equivalent.  (Yes, I'm aware that I've just restated the well-known equivalence between maximality of subgroups and primitivity of the corresponding permutation actions.)  So consider two distinct 3-element subsets, say $a$ and $b$, that are equivalent under $E$.

There are several cases, depending on how much $a$ and $b$ overlap.  I'll do the hardest case, where $|a\cap b|=2$; it will be obvious how to simplify the proof when $a\cap b$ is smaller.  Let $a=\{x,y,z\}$ and $b=\{y,z,w\}$; here and in what follows, elements with different names are supposed to be distinct.  Let $\pi$ be a permutation in $S$ sending $x,y,z,w,u$ to $y,z,w,u,v$, respectively (where $u$ and $v$ are new, different numbers).  So $\pi$ sends $a$ to $b$, sends $b$ to $c=\{z,w,u\}$, and sends $c$ to $d=\{w,u,v\}$.  As $E$ is equivariant and $a$ is equivalent to $b$, we conclude that $b$ is equivalent to $c$ and $c$ is equivalent to $d$.  Therefore, $E$ makes the disjoint sets $a$ and $d$ equivalent.  Invoking equivariance of $E$ again, we find that it makes *any* two disjoint elements of $P_3$ equivalent.  But then, given any two elements $e,f\in P_3$, we can find $g\in P_3$ disjoint from both and thus equivalent to both; it follows that $E$ makes $e$ and $f$ equivalent; since $e$ and $f$ were arbitrary, this contradicts the fact that $E$ is non-trivial.